# Magento show div on checkout from observer

Tags: json, magento, checkout

I am writing a custom Magento module to check if a guest user is using an already registered email address.
The module uses the `controller_action_predispatch_checkout_onepage_saveBilling` observer to do the checks. 
What I’m struggling with is how to show (or dynamically insert) a div with an error message somewhere at the bottom of the billing panel.
The observer is working correctly, but now I’m stuck on displaying the error to the user. I was using the following method which will display a JS alert but I now need to include a clickable link..

```
        $response = array('error' => -1, 'message' => Mage::helper('core')->__($errorMsg));
        return $controller->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($response));
```

Any ideas how to accomplish this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I think is :

1) create your own jquery click function on the continue button after billing address is entered.

2) Create a div below email input with no text inside it.Keep this div hidden.

3) When user fills the billing details and click on continue, send an ajax request to your custom controller.

4) Check if customer is already present for that email id,if YES : make email ID blank & Make the div in step 2) visible and add the warning message in its innethtml text. Add e.preventDefault() to prevent default savebilling ajax actions of magento.

5) If email id is not present. return true which will continue the default actions of magento.

Any Session setting-getting variables can be little difficult as most of the work on checkout is done by AJAX without refreshing the page.

Comment: That seems like a far better idea than what I was trying!! Thanks :)

Comment: Glad it helped, I always prefer keeping the default magento untouched. Just have upper custom validations to make things smooth without affecting the internal workflows. :)

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is register your error message in your controller, and check for it in your template file.

So in your controller:

```
 Mage::register('error_msg', $myErrorMsg);
```

And then in your template file:

```
 $errorMsg = Mage::registry('error_msg');
 if(!is_null($errorMsg)):
      //do your magic here
 endif;
```